# Will a 4-wire resolver work?

Tags: motor, sensor

I am not an EE. Most resolvers I come across have 6-wires:

[image]

I have even come across 5-wire resolvers. Could we get this down to 4 wires?

For example, an RVDT (Rotary Variable Differential Transformer)
requires only 4 wires: 2 for the primary coil, 2 for the secondary coils if they are wired in series.

Of course, with RVDTs, the secondary coils run parallel to each other.

[image]

What if the secondary coils were wired in series, where the secondary coils were perpendicular to each other like in a resolver?

Could I still determine the angle of the rotor?

[image]

Comment: Since you'd get the *sum* Sin(θ) and Cos (θ), how would you distinguish quadrants??

Answer (score 0):

You can get down to 4 wires, if you have  star or Y connected 3 windings, and you have steel rotor, and you calculate the inductance of the windings. Assuming you have a microcontroller smart enough to read such a thing - use AC signals at high frequency to messure inductance, rather than slow signals that are used in your examples. And either read the windings one by one or try to use different AC frequencies on each winding.

3 wires if you have delta connected 3 winding, but reader is more complex - adc and dac on the same outputs. And reading is more complex too - need to account for a long path too

Comment: Will the secondary windings still remain perpendicular to each other?

Comment: @apprenticeprogrammer 3 windings with 120* between each is easy to do and what is usually done. 2 windings with 90* between them would require excentric rotor and would be sensitive to noise and require much more complex program. But yes, both are possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can I find more information about these configurations?

Comment: @apprenticeprogrammer i've not seen them being used in this role, i just assume it is possible. But closest things are https://mri-q.com/real-v-imaginary.html and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchro but neither is popular at precise angle measurment today afaik.  Because they require much more complex program to operate than simpler options with more wires.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I have to use the resolvers we already have so I wouldn't be able to use the 3-winding method. I also don't think I have the option in modifying the rotor. It seems to me the cheapest option for me is too use a 5-wire resolver. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @apprenticeprogrammer so, you want to use an existing detector circuit and rotor? What can you change?

Comment: Not much. The existing resolver and coil configurations must stay. I can only modify the wiring of the resolver after it has exited the resolver itself as indicated in the photo above. I have confirmed that simply tying two lines together works and reduces the total amount of wires by 1. I was just curious if simply tying these coils in series was possible.